# Print data from search in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, search, printing

I am a "beginner" in this area and I am building a system for my company.
I have a page called "busca.php" that by entering the "tracking code" its search in the mysql database and returns me all the order data that has this code.
The following code:
http://notes.io/qtAs

And after i see all the data of the order , i need to print the shipping label.
The variables:
nome
endereco
cep
cidade
estado

In other words, I can not give the command to print the page because I do not need all the variables, only stated above.

Is it possible that by clicking on "print" in this search page it returns me like a pop-up only with these variables and have open the Print page to choose a printer?
 
If so, how?
 
 
 
Thanks.

Comment: You'll have better luck getting people to answer your question if you don't force them to read all your code but just the relevant parts.  That being said it seems the answer is to change your sql statement from `select *` to `select nome, ..., estado`

Comment: I added a button on the page redirecting to "print.php", but the page gives to me all the date of db in these variables. not only the data on the variables searched in the previous page. What can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need all information. You could just change the * in you query, which just grabs all columns, to the info you do need.

For example, because I don't know what your query looks like.

Change:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
```

To:

```
SELECT nome, endereco, cep, cidade, estado FROM `table`
```

Comment: I added a button on the page redirecting to "print.php", but the page gives to me all the date of db in these variables.  not only the data on the  variables searched in the previous page.   What can i do ?

Comment: Can show me the code of print.php,  Just edit your original question.

Comment: In "buscar.php" i put one button redirecting to "print.php".   but the "print.php" shows all data of the db , not only the data searched before.   Code: http://notes.io/qtAJ